# yii before actions for specified action

Tags: yii, action

I know controller have a method called:CController:beforeAction()
It will be called before every action in current controller.
But how to make it only work before "actions"?

```
public function actions(){
    return array(
        //trigger something like beforeaction only for action "uploader" 
        'uploader' => array(
            'class' =>'',

        ),
    ); 
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nice question. I think there isn't anyway to disable running beforeAction on specific action. If you have beforeAction inside your controller, this method will run before **any** action. But you can do this instead:

```
   protected function beforeAction($action)
   {
       if($action->id != "uploader")
       {
          //do some stuff here
       }

       return parent::beforeAction($action);
   }
```